# MetaMask SDK popup shows even if i have the extension

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, blockchain, vite, metamask

I am making a DAPP using React Vite, and i want to switch from using `window.ethereum` to MMSDK.

[Here](https://github.com/Sivayogeith/solidity_eth/tree/MMSDK) is my github branch for migrating to MMSDK.

So, what happens is that even if I have the extension it opens the popup when the <kbd>Submit</kbd> Button is clicked.

Here are the screenshots for this:

My Extenstion:

[image: My Metamask Extenstion]

If I click <kbd>Submit</kbd>:

There are no errors but the popup comes even though I have the extension.

Also, there is a warning when the button is clicked:

[image: warning]

[image: If I click Submit]

That is the main problem, but also if I click <kbd>Install Metamask Extenstion</kbd> it does not open the chrome extenstion page; instead it gives this error:

[image: EROOOORRR!!!!]

This not working code is also deployed [here](https://solidity-eth-git-mmsdk-sivayogeith.vercel.app/), if you want to try it on your device.

Here is my submit function:

```
const handleMethodSubmit = async (methodName, params, stateMutability) => {
        try {
            const method = contract.methods[methodName];
            const provider = MMSDK.getProvider();

            const accounts = await provider.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
                params: [],
            });
            const account = accounts[0];
            console.log(account);

            if (stateMutability === "view") {
                const result = await method(...params).call({
                    from: account,
                });
                console.log("Method result:", result);
                log("Method result: " + result);
            } else {
                const gasEstimate = await method(...params).estimateGas({
                    from: account,
                });

                const transaction = {
                    from: account,
                    to: contractAddress,
                    data: method(...params).encodeABI(),
                    gas: gasEstimate.toString(),
                    value: "0x0",
                    maxFeePerGas: "0x5F5E100",
                    maxPriorityFeePerGas: "0x5F5E100",
                    chainId: "0xaa36a7",
                };

                const result = await provider.request({
                    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
                    params: [
                        {
                            ...transaction,
                            feeMarketBid: {
                                maxFeePerGas: transaction.maxFeePerGas,
                                maxPriorityFeePerGas:
                                    transaction.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                });

                console.log("Transaction receipt:", result);
                log("Transaction receipt: " + result);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error executing method:", error);
            log("Error executing method: " + error);
        }
    };
```

If you want the full code it is [on my github](https://github.com/Sivayogeith/solidity_eth/blob/MMSDK/land_ui/src/components/ContractMethods/ContractMethods.jsx).

At last, I want to mention that on my laptop the [test dapp](https://c0f4f41c-2f55-4863-921b-sdk-docs.github.io/test-dapp/) given by MetaMask works well.

PS: Also if you want to checkout my deployed project without MMSDK, it is [here](https://land-ui.vercel.app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who is facing this issue, I posted this question on the MetaMask community and someone helped me there.

So, [here](https://community.metamask.io/t/metamask-sdk-in-react-popup-shows-even-if-i-have-the-extension/26152) is the link to that post.

Hope this helps!